# Is it possible/ How is it possible to access the input of a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can the text in the input field that the user is currently writing, be accessed, via the facebook api? This info is needed to aid the user when he is writing a message, with the help of NLP. But other use-cases like spellchecking or Grammer would also make a lot of sense. 
In my case, I want to implement a bot that is able to analyze the content of the input and give instant feedback. Basically an NLP Spellchecker, so I also need text highlighting for the text in the input field, but that is another question.

However, I only found information about accessing sent messages.

Comment: Are you talking about a messenger bot? No, what the user types is not available while they are typing it, only after they send the message.